# How to make Sure callback has been called only proceed to next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have simplied function that perform file upload function like this.

```
var a = {
    fileRepositoryFrame : {
        properties : {
            //file upload function
        },
        successCallback : function d(f) {
            //do something              
        },
        failCallback : function d(f, g, h) {
            posted = false;
        //do something
        }
    }
};

$('input[name="file.name"]').val(fileName);
```

Basically i want to set some flag when it is successCallback, for normal file size , it does not have issues.However when the file size is bigger,its does not wait the file done uploaded, then its continue to next part of code, so the flag is not able to set.I'm not familiar with callback, do it have any way to wait until the call back is done only perform next line .Please kindly assist on this.Thanks

Comment: If you use the async pattern properly you don't need to use flags at all. Just call the relevant logic from within the callback handler which has been executed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , there are not only flag is setting on that method inside successCallBack, it have another logic on it, i just done some research which setTimeOut able to fix this kind of issues, but that is not a good practice which we cant confirm what will be the exact file size, so looking is it still got another solution for it.

Comment: In that case it would help to see a more representative version of your code. I'm sure the advice will be the same as my first comment though; use the async pattern properly